# How to delete files and sub-folders from folders not starting with a specific name in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, delete-file, subdirectory

I have a directory of `D:\data` which has many folders containing data from map layers `(D:\data\parks, D:\data\buildings, D:\data\rivers)`.

I want to delete the contents of all of these sub-folders which includes both files and sub-folders, except any folders within 'data' that start with the name `'raster'` i.e

`D:\data\raster_aerialimage` .

I have some code which deletes one of the folders, but I need to loop through all folders and specify only folders that do not start with 'raster', how can I append this code, or should I start with something brand new?

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("D:\data\parks\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dir /A:D` to walk through all the directories together with `findstr` to return only those directories that do not start with `raster`. Then use a `for /F` loop to parse the output:

```
pushd "D:\data"
if ErrorLevel 1 goto :EOF
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%P in ('
    dir /B /A:D "*.*" ^| findstr /L /V /I /B /C:"raster"
') do (
    rmdir /S /Q "%%~fP"
)
popd
```

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl - I seem to get an error 'D:\>(rmdir /S /Q "airports") The system cannot find the file specified.

This seems to happen for some other folders as well.

Comment: Hmm... `dir /A:D` should return only directories that do exist... perhaps you do not have sufficient access rights to these directories, or to some sub-items? What if you try with `dir /B /A:D-L "D:\data"`?

Comment: I seem to get the same message. I have moved the data onto both my local C: drive and also a Z: drive but the same message appears. I am able to read and write on all three drives so bit of a mystery!

Comment: What are the exact names of the problematic directories? do you have [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled in your script?

Comment: The problem isn't because it is trying to search for files and not folders? (Just reading the message 'The system cannot find the file specified', as they are folders that I wish to delete).

Comment: The `/A:D` option filters for directories -- see `dir /?` --, so that should not be the problem; how and from where do you run the script? what is your current working directory? I [updated](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36921317/2) the script so that can start it from anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using robocopy.exe which is available in all newer Windows versions:

```
@echo off
set folder=D:\data
set except=raster
set "MT=%TEMP%\DelFolder_%RANDOM%"

mkdir %MT%
:: mirror an empty dir to a folder tree will delete it
robocopy "%MT%" "%folder%" /MIR /XD %except%* /R:1 /W:1
rmdir /S /Q "%MT%"
```

Note the wildcard star just behind the `%except%`variable.

It's fast and it copes with very long pathnames.

Comment: This seems to work very well - the only problem is it deletes the folders not named raster, I actually only want to delete the contents of the folders, not the folders themselves.